# 'Incomplete response received from application'

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, put

I am currently running an API on a Plesk web server with Node.js configured and running. My post requests and get requests seem to work and return perfectly however when I am trying to send a put request I am told that there was an 'Incomplete response received from application'.

After looking at a few threads I saw that it could be to do with an issue with a 'secret_key' however this makes me confused as to why this would only happen on a put request and also as to how I could rectify the problem not having console access.

The code for the put request can be found below:

```
app.put('/players', function (req, res) {
   connection.query('UPDATE `players` SET `playerID`=?,`money`=?,`bounty`=?', [req.body.playerID ,req.body.money, req.body.bounty], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});
```

As an example, when sending a request I would send the following body:

```
{"playerID":53,"money":2332,"bounty":4}
```

as JSON which would return that error.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Spotted the issue. In my SQL request I never specify which row to update. I specify what fields to update but never include 'WHERE playerID='

Unfortunately this is quite a specific error and won't benefit a lot of people. :(